# Action of a Dirac fermion

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, quantum-electrodynamics, dirac-equation

When studying an introductory course on particle physics, I came across the following question:

**What is the action describing electromagnetic fields coupled to charged fermions?**

I have already seen the Dirac Lagrangian  but I cannot seem to find a way of coupling electromagnetic fields to charged fermions with it. Any help would be great!

Comment: Wikipedia: [Quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#Mathematical_formulation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can take the coupling $\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu$ with a prefactor $e$ that determines the strength of the coupling.

This works since $\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi  A_\mu$ is a scalar with respect to spinors($\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi$ is scalar, $A_\mu$ is a scalar) and vectors($\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi$ is a vector, $A_\mu$ is a vector, their contraction is a scalar).

Formally, one includes this term in the quantum electrodynamics lagrangian through the covariant derivative $D_\mu = \partial_\mu +ieA_\mu$ that replaces the $\partial_\mu$ in the Dirac lagrangian. Since the new field $A_\mu$ is a new degree of freedom, one has to include all possible terms containing it. However, one can argue that they can all be reduced to $-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}$ with the $F^{\mu\nu}$ that one knows from classical electromagnetism(without covariant derivatives in it). One gets $$\mathcal{L}=\bar{\psi}\left( i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m\right)\psi \to \bar{\psi}\left( i\gamma^\mu D_\mu-m\right)\psi -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu} = \bar{\psi}\left( i\gamma^\mu \partial_\mu -m\right)\psi -e\bar{\psi}\gamma^\mu \psi A_\mu -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}. $$

Comment: Thank you, that makes alot of sense ! However I do have two additional questions. First of all, is this exact method (same transformation for the derivative) applicable to any field ? (for example the gravitational field or something like that) and also, is it possible to couple any kind of particle (fermions, bosons, etc.) to that field through this method ? Secondly, does applying this transformation to any Lagrangian density always produce a gauge invariant Lagrangian density ?

Comment: 1) The form of the covariant derivative follows directly from symmetry(U(1) for the electromagnetic field) and is exact for this symmetry and the right type of gauge boson($s=1$). Therefore, it is different for SU(2) and SU(3) since they have another symmetry. Gravitation is also different since its gauge boson has $s=2$ in contrast to the other gauge bosons that have $s=1$. The covariant derivative is a general method to make terms with derivatives gauge invariant, so it applies to coupling of general bosons and fermions to our gauge field.

Comment: Its hard to understand all this without seeing how the equations come together, so please search for this in your desired book(I heavily recommend Schwartz).

Comment: 2) By construction, covariant derivatives acting on fields transform like the fields itself. In order to include gauge invariance into a Lagragian, one therefore has to replace normal derivatives by covariant ones. One also has to make sure that the form of the terms is gauge invariant. Third, one has to include the kinetic terms of the gauge fields in the Lagrangian(I will correct this in my answer).